# On integration over distribution.

Tags: probability, integration, generating-functions, machine-learning, data-analysis

When I read various journal articles related to machine learning, I often face integrals over distribution.

In an article I am reading now, for example, a risk function associated with distribution $\phi$ is defined by $$ R_i(\theta) = \int f_L(f_\theta(x),y) \, d\phi(x,y),$$ where

- $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ are a feature space and a label space, respectively.
- $f_\theta:\mathcal{X}\to\mathcal{Y}$ is a given model parameterized by $\theta\in\Theta$,
- $f_L:\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}\to\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$ is a loss function, and
- $\phi$ is the data generating distributions.

---

In addition to the above case and the others (even not related to this field), I have seen many times integration formulas over distributions. However, whenever I encountered them, I couldn't grasp what it is.

Rather, I am familiar with the following equation:
$$
\int f_L(x) p_X(x) \, dx,
$$
where $f_L(x)$ is a cost (or reward) function achieved by an event $x$, and $p_X(x)$ is a probability that an event $x$ occurred.

Can someone please let me know what the integral over a distribution means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you lack relevant knowledge on [Riemann–Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral)

In the Probability theory，the Expectation of Discrete distribution and continuous distribution can be written uniformly as Riemann–Stieltjes integral form, that is
$$ E_X(f(x)) = \int f(x)dF(x)$$

where $F(x)$ is the  cumulative distribution function of random variable $X$,
you can roughly think that $dF(x) = p(x)dx$

I hope it is useful to you.
Sorry, if it didn't help you.

Comment: I think $F(x)$ is not the probability distribution function (pdf) but the cumulative distribution function (cdf) of a random variable $X$, whereas $p(x)$ is the pdf. Am I wrong? Is it fine to call $F(x)$ probability distribution function?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I may forget the Exact name of $F(x)$

Comment: I don't know if your question has been resolved